# Computing confidence region for Gaussian mixture model

Tags: normal-distribution, spatial, python, mixture-distribution

I have a 2-d Gaussian mixture model and would like to compute a confidence region for it. Our application is that the two dimensions are latitude and longitude; that is, we want to say something like "the model is 95% confident that the true point lies within this (perhaps noncontiguous) region".

In other words, I think what we want is to find the contour which contains 95% (or whatever) of the probability volume in the model.

My questions:

1. Is there a simple and fast way to do this?
2. Are there any libraries which can do this, ideally in Python?

We need the region as a (multi)polygon object which we can then pass around the rest of our software, not a plot.

Comment: Are you sure you have a guassian **mixture** model and not a **multivariate** gaussian distribution?

Comment: @Max, pretty sure. It's a `sklearn.mixture.GMM` object: http://scikit-learn.github.com/scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html

Comment: This is just me thinking out loud. Someone more familiar with the material may have a better solution. It looks like you have access to the component distributions. For each of the component distributions, you could generate a 95% confidence region. The combination of all of the 95% confidence regions on the component distributions will give you a region covering 95% of the mixture distribution, I think.

Comment: It is an interesting question to come up with a region containing $95\%$ of the mass, but is that really a $95\%$ confidence region?

Comment: @Max, that was my first thought too, but it turns out the contour in the mixture is not the union of the contours of the components. So even if I knew how to scale the confidence ellipses of the components according to component weight, that wouldn't help.

Comment: @Douglas, I thought it was for the following reason: Suppose that you drew 100 random points from the mixture. You would expect 95 of those to be from the region containing 95% of the mass, which seems like the same expectation as a confidence region. If I'm missing something, I'm all ears.

Comment: Normally, a confidence interval/region arises when you are estimating a parameter. The confidence region is a random variable. Which parameter are you estimating, and what are the other confidence regions you could get instead?

Comment: @Douglas, we are estimating the location of a point.

Comment: In some models, the points correspond to sets of parameters. In a mixed Gaussian model they don't, and I would not call this set a confidence region.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is possible for instance to compute what is the probability contained in a ball $\mathcal{B}(c,r)$. I suppose that your gaussian mixture writes

$$p(x) = \sum_{j=1}^K \mathcal{N}(x;\mu_j,\Sigma_j)\mathbb{P}(J=j)$$

There exist elementary pieces of code to make an algorithm to compute $F(c,r)=\int_{\mathcal{B}(c,r)} p(x)dx $ for each $(c,r)\in \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}^+$ which I will detail further. First note that since for a fixed $c$, the function $r\mapsto F(c,r)$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$ then a search by dichotomy can numerically solve the problem of finding $r$ such as, for a given $c$, $F(c,r)=95\%$. More efficient methods such as the secant method exist.

To handle the general case, if the matrices $\Sigma_j$ have no particular form except that they are positive definite, you may have to use [wikipedia link to the generalized non central chi square cumulative function][1]. For this purpose, the C source code will be useful [source code from Robert Davies' website][2]. You'll find the related documentation [on Robert Davies' page][3] and in his paper [The Distribution of a Linear Combination of Chi Squared Random Variables][4] in which he adopts the same symbols.

If the matrices $\Sigma_j$ are each one proportional to the identity matrix, you may use either the already mentioned **generalized non central chi square cumulative function** or the **non central chi square cumulative function** which is more common (see [Non Central Chi Square Law][5]). This function is available in MATLAB for instance.

Now, here is how you can use it.

$$p(x) = \sum_{j=1}^K \mathcal{N}(x;\mu_j,\Sigma_j)\mathbb{P}(J=j)$$

is the density of a variable that we call $X_J$ where for each $i \in \{1,...,K\}$, the variable $X_i$ is a gaussian random variable which has a probability density function given by $\mathcal{N}(x;\mu_j,\Sigma_j)$ and where $J$ is a random discrete variable on the set $\{1,...,K\}$ independent of each $X_i$, and which follows the known law $\mathbb{P}(J=j)$.

Since we can decompose the probability
$$\int_{\mathcal{B}(c,r)} p(x)dx = \mathbb{P}\left(X_J \in \mathcal{B}(c,r) \right) = \sum_{j=1}^K \mathbb{P}\left(X_J \in \mathcal{B}(c,r) |J=j\right)\mathbb{P}(J=j)$$

What we need to compute is $\mathbb{P} \left(X_J \in \mathcal{B}(c,r) |J=j\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\|X_j-c\|^2 \leq r^2 \right)$.

Since $X_j-c$ is a gaussian random variable which follows $\mathcal{N}(x;\mu_j-c,\Sigma_j)$, then $\|X_j-c\|^2$ follows a (generalized non central) chi squared law.

Some derivations must be done to identify the parameters (which we call $\theta_j$) of this law. (I can be more explicit on demand).

Then the only thing remaining to do is to evaluate the Chi Squared cumulative function (which we call $S$) of this chi squared law at $r$.

Finally : 
$$F(c,r)=\int_{\mathcal{B}(c,r)} p(x)dx =
\sum_{j=1}^K S(r;\theta_j)\mathbb{P}(J=j) $$

Then, one can apply a dichotomy or a secant method to find the better approximation to $r$ which ensusres $\mathcal{B}(c,r)$ to contain 95%.

---

If you are in the particular case where the matrices $\Sigma_j$ are diagonal, then you can find a rectangular region. By rectangle I mean a domain which is a cartesian product of intervals. You'll need the **erf** function, which is related to the cumulative function of a gaussian probability density function.

---

To answer another question posted : The union of the contours contains exacly or more than 95% if each contour contains 95% of probability.

Here is why. Let $E_i$ be the contour such as $\mathbb{P}(X_i \in E_i)=95\%$ and let $\bigcup_{i=1}^K  E_i $ be the union of the contours then

$$ \int_{ \bigcup_{i=1}^K E_i} p(x)dx = \mathbb{P}\left(X_J \in \bigcup_{i=1}^K E_i\right)$$
$$= \sum_{i=1}^K \mathbb{P}\left(X_J \in  \bigcup_{i=1}^K E_i |J=j\right)\mathbb{P}(J=j)$$

in which each term $\mathbb{P}\left(X_J \in \bigcup_{i=1}^K E_i \Big| J=j \right) \geq 95\%$. Finally, because $\mathbb{P}(J=j)$ sums to 1, this last line is a weighted average of values greater than 95%, thus the sum is greater than 95%.

Comment: I think this could be improved with formatting, editing, and the like.

Comment: To compute this, $\mathbb{P} \left(X_J \in \mathcal{B}(c,r) |J=j\right)$, we do not need to borrow a Chi-square distribution because we can compute it directly using the CDF of the standard normal distribution.